# How to work with the sender ActorRef in akka

Tags: scala, akka, higher-order-functions

Long time ago, I learned than this code:

```
def doSome(ref: ActorRef, msg: AnyRef): Unit = {
  ... some routine ...

  ref ! msg
}

def receive = {
  case x: Foo => doSome(sender(), x)
}
```

must be

```
...

def receive = {
  case x: Foo => 
    val s = sender()
    doSome(s, x)
}
```

because sender() is a function and before apply somebody may change a context.sender() value

**question 1**: is there truth for non Future function? or it safe to write like in first variant?

**question 2**: is there some way to write like this?

```
def receive = {
  case x: Foo => sendrer() {s => doSome(s, x)}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is there truth for non Future function?" Do you have a function inside your actor that returns a future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `sender()` will stay the same as long as the receive behavior for the given message is executed.

So to answer your first question: Yes it is safe to do it like in the first variant as long as you

1. do not assign the value returned by `sender()` to a field inside your actor
2. pass that value somewhere outside your actor

However, I would not recommend assigning the result of `sender()` to a variable. Rather than that, I'd suggest calling `sender()` and directly send it a message (this would be my answer to question 2):

```
def receive = {
  case x: Foo => doSome(x)
}

def doSome(msg: Foo) = {
  // your logic here
  sender() ! msg
}
```